# Refresh or Timer for 1:35 p.m. ET and 8:00 p.m. ET?

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

Basically, how would I make an event handler for when the time is 1:35 PM ET and 8:00 ET? I need to run a refresh method at those times.

Comment: Can't you just run two timers?

Comment: Can you explain further? I don't quite understand how it would work.

Comment: Okay, you don't have a timer I thought you actually have. So why don't just have 2 scheduled tasks? [Write a wrapper in C#.](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a close look to the [Quartz.Net Framework](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Otherwise, if you want to keep detached from third parties, I suggest you to have a single [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) that runs every minute.

On every minute, you should check if `Now` is one of the trigger times you mean to refresh your objects.